# Slow GUI update of Outlook Desktop inbox after moving email with makeEwsRequestAsync to subfolder

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, office-js, exchangewebservices

**Use case:** I am moving an email in a JavaScript-based Office add-in with an EWS request to the Exchange server `makeEwsRequestAsync(...<m:MoveItem>...)` from the inbox to a subfolder. The call succeeds, and the email move is confirmed in the returned XML response (OSF.DDA.AsyncResult).

**Problem:** It takes a few seconds for the Outlook Desktop inbox to be updated (= email disappears from inbox and shows in subfolder), even after the XML confirmation has been received that the email has been successfully moved.

**Question:** Can I somehow notify the GUI of the Outlook host about the fact than an email has been moved from the inbox to a subfolder? Or is there any other way to ensure a quick update of the Outlook host GUI?

**Environment:**
Windows 10 Pro desktop with Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO 32-bit, developing JavaScript-based Office add-in for Outlook using a Microsoft 365 E5 instant sandbox

P.S. Raised a GitHub issue for this for [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2559), will update both posts with any outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do that in a JS addin. If you only target desktop Outlook under Windows, COM (VSTO) addin would be a better choice - it works with the local (cached) store and `MailItem.Move` call will be immediately visible to the end user.